# Help calculating this volume

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Being $x,y,z \geq 0$ , calculate the volume bounded by $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{2y} + \sqrt{3z} = 1$

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Did you mean to fund the volume of the region $\mathrm{X}$ defined by the relations $x, y,z \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{2y}+\sqrt{3z}=1$?

Comment: Did you tried use some change of variables? What if $x=u^2,\ 2y=v^2\ \mbox{and}\ 3z=w^2$?

Comment: I´ll  try to make that change

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested, use $x=u^2,\ 2y=v^2\ \mbox{and}\ 3z=w^2$. Then your volume is
$$
V = \int \int \int \frac43 u v w \; du \;dv \;dw
$$
with $u,v,w > 0$ and $u + v + w \le 1$. The boundaries can be implemented by

$$
V = \int_0^{1} \int_0^{1-u} \int_0^{1-u-v} \frac43 u v w \; du \;dv \;dw
$$
so
$$
V = \frac46 \int_0^{1} \int_0^{1-u} u v (1-u-v)^2 \; du \;dv
$$

$$
V = \frac46 \frac{1}{12} \int_0^{1} u (u-1)^4 \; du =  \frac46 \frac{1}{12}  \frac{1}{30} =  \frac{1}{540} \simeq 0.00185
$$

Comment: Wow, a downvote on this one. I'm looking forward to the alternative solution to come up from this enthusiast coworker.